# Broadcast audiostream to multiple devices

Tags: android, wifi, audio-streaming, rtp

I am using android `AudioStream` to communicate between 2 android devices on wifi, both ways. Is there any way to broadcast an audio message on multiple devices, in the same time ?

Is using multiple AudioStreams, one for each device, a possible way? I need to broadcast to 40 receivers. Will the message be delayed if I use multiple AudioStreams ?

Do you know other solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to stream all devices using AudioGroup, you just need to create separate AudioStream for each clients and join them to one AudioGroup. That is it.

```
AudioGroup audio = new AudioGroup();
audio.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);

AudioStream stream1 = new AudioStream(yourLocalIP);
stream1.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
stream1.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_SEND_ONLY);
stream1.associate(firstClientIP, anyport);
stream1.join(audio);

AudioStream stream2 = new AudioStream(yourLocalIP);
stream2.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
stream2.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_SEND_ONLY);
stream2.associate(secondClientIP, anyport);
stream2.join(audio);
```